# Cold air under base board heat from floor

Tags: floor, radiator

My wood floor doesn't go all the way to the wall underneath the base board radiator. I have a draft coming from that section. - what can I put down to stop the draft and looks nice. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Drafts should be stopped at their source. Is it coming from the basement? From outside? Sealing this gap will just move where the leak enters the room. It won't resolve the heat loss issue.

Comment: Wow that is huge, I would want to fill most of the gap with the same type of flooring, then use 1/4 round from the floor to the wall to reduce the flow. Sealing may be tough as it looks like an older home.

Answer (score 1):

You have baseboard heat AND forced air? Because if you HAD baseboard heat at one point and someone CHANGED to forced air, but just left the old baseboards there, I would consider removing them, then taking the hardwood all the way to the base of the wall.

*If you are still using the baseboard heaters*, then you have to be concerned for the air flow coming into them, which is likely why someone left the hardwood out of that space. In other words filling that gap may result in restricting the air flow into the bottom of the baseboard heaters, reducing their effectiveness. You would have to then try to find out where the draft is actually coming from and fix it there.